# Will surface samples from Mars orbit the planet in a spherical capsule until captured?

Tags: mars, nasa, esa, rendezvous, sample-return

The abstract of the interesting 2001 NASA JPL paper [Covering a Sphere with Retroreflectors](https://www-robotics.jpl.nasa.gov/publications/Daniel_Clouse/clouse01_aeroconf.pdf) says:

> Abstract- One of the future missions for Mars involves returning a soil sample from the Martian surface to Earth. The sample will be deposited in a spherical canister, shot into Mars orbit and then subsequently captured by a spacecraft for the return journey. This paper discusses how retroreflectors can be placed on the orbiting sample canister with the objective of maximizing returned light from a scanning laser system. The retroreflectors are vital for acquisition of the sample canister during the terminal rendezvous phase (< 5 km) of the capture.

Twenty years have passed so the mission design has likely evolved, so I'd like to ask:

**Question(s):**

1. Will surface samples from Mars be in a **spherical capsule** until captured?
2. Will the samples (no matter the shape of the carrier) be in **an actual orbit** around Mars, or will the trajectory be sub-orbital?

There are some problems with the optics calculations, no ranging laser is going to have a coherence length of 5 kilometers, so the interference effects between retroreflectors will not cause the nulls and minima they suggest. Yes, as discussed in [What is the longest coherence length stimulated-emission beam demonstrated?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/269953/83380) there are reports of multi-kilometer coherence lengths in fiber lasers, but *you have to work extremely hard* to make this happen.

[This answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/44888/12102) to *What kind of rocket will ESA(?) launch from Mars? Who will build it?* is well-sourced and contains some nice graphics, but there are no details I can see of the sample-containing object that will be captured then flown back to Earth.

[image]

Clearly "[it's only a model](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m3dZl3yfGpc)" (longer [version](https://youtu.be/SQCArh_R9dY))

---

The NASA-credited images below are from the BBC News article [Europe pushes ahead with 'dune buggy' Mars rover](https://www.bbc.com/news/science-environment-53062617) and come from the question linked above.

[What precautions are planned to prevent samples returned from Mars crashing and releasing organisms on Earth?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/45035/12102) is a separate but related question.

[image: The Fetch rover will bring the tubes it's collected back to its landing station] [image: The tubes will be put in a rocket and fired high above Mars]

> **left:** The Fetch rover will bring the tubes it's collected back to its landing station **right:** The tubes will be put in a rocket and fired high above Mars

Comment: I don't see the question @uhoh, the title doesn't seem to match the body, and there's no actual question in the body. Are you asking if this is the method they plan to use?

Comment: @GdD Thanks! I almost always include a summary/indicator of the actual question, but it seems that I forgot this time. That's probably related to the fact that I'm supposed to be actually doing something right now rather than playing Stack Exchange ;-) I've just added one now, up near the top.

Comment: Surely you have asking questions down to a science by now @uhoh!

Comment: @GdD yes, the same way I had drinking beer "down to a science" a million years ago and these days *drinking coffee*; it's simply an addiction.

Comment: @GdD related: [Am I the only one getting addicted to this site? How do you manage time doing other things?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3850/284619) and [Addiction to Math Stack Exchange](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/26466/284619) there's some in main meta as well [How can I keep from getting addicted to Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/4004/303080) and [How to stop my husband from answering your questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/105045/303080) and [“Ban myself” button in user profiles](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/32299/303080)

Comment: and [Is there anything like Stack Exchange Anonymous?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/61758/303080) and in Psychology & Neuroscience SE: [Is StackExchange.com Addiction Dangerous?](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/q/1465/19214) and [What is the motivation model behind StackExchange?](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/q/25253/19214)

Comment: It's...just...too...good @uhoh!

Comment: a suborbital capture would be *very* hard and would need new techniques; orbital rendezvous is well understood.

Answer (score 2):

Many sources. (eg [this one](https://www.esa.int/Science_Exploration/Human_and_Robotic_Exploration/Exploration/Mars_sample_return)) mention the samples orbiting Mars in a "basketball-sized" container until collected by the Earth Return Orbiter. I haven't seen any authoritative ones saying it's also *shaped* like a basketball.